# React native in styles if expression

Tags: react-native

I'm listing data in Touchableopacity.List item lenghts between 10-350 characters. Each list item is bordered like box and them height is static(150 px). I just want to do is make the height dynamic.
That's what I tryed.

Styles

```
listItem:{
    flex: 1,
    width: '100%',
    height: 150,
    backgroundColor:'#E7C287',
    borderWidth: 1,  
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',  
        },    
listItem2:{
    flex: 1,
    width: '100%',
    height: 150,
    backgroundColor:'#E7C287',
    borderWidth: 1,  
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',  
        },
```

My solution is

```
      { Object.keys(text).length <200 ?
          
           <View
     
           style={listStyles.listItem}>
           
             
         <Text         
           style={ fontstill}
            
             
             >{text}</Text>
         </View>
        
       :
      
       <View
     
        style={listStyles.listItem2}>
        
          
      <Text         
        style={ fontstill}
         
          
          >{text}</Text>
      </View>
       }
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

How can I make it for 3 condition like  `listStyles.listItem3`

Comment: you have already opened a js block when you wrote `style={` so you should remove the curly braces from the count, `sytle={[ count < 250 ? .....]}`

Comment: Yes as I mentioned I tryed it. It says same

Comment: i don't feel comfortable using the array syntax :p, try `style={count < 250 ? style1 : style2}`

Comment: Yeah I find it on searching, also this way says same

Comment: oh now i see, you can't define a variable inside jsx, you should define it outside the render or the return

Comment: But the text comes list, it has to work for all items

Comment: yeah, but instead of declaring the count inside the text, you can declare it right after the declartion of the text

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your Text JSX with

```
    <Text 
      //There is the I want to make it dynamic
      style={Object.keys(text).length} < 250 ? listStyles.listItem : listStyles.listItem2}>      
      {text}</Text>
```

Comment: I added to bottom

Comment: Remove the "}" character after "250"

Comment: I'm sorry, i made a mistake. I have updated the answer with the changes (just removed the extra {})

Answer (score 0):

You should separate the declaration of the variable from the jsx

```js
import React from 'react';
import { listStyles } from './styles/ListStyles';

const [stil, setstil] = useState(listStyles.listItem);

const text = item1.sample;

const ListStyles = () => {
  const count = Object.keys(text).length;
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
        <View style={stil}>
          <Text 
            style={count < 250 
            ? listStyles.listItem 
            : listStyles.listItem2
            }>
              {text}
            </Text>
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}
```

Comment: Still same can't find, I make a solution but it works for 2 conditions. How can I make it for 3